INterpretting residuals from a GAMM model
I am trying to run GAMs using binomial data (link=logit) in r with the mgcv package. This is to attempt to describe which variables describe species presence using presence (1) and absence (0) data as the response and a suite of environmental and social variables as the predictor. I use a multi-level approach incorporating random effects. My data is spatially autocorrelated so I also account for that using x and y.
The code I am using appears to be working fine however, when I plot residuals I am left with two distinct lines and I am not sure how to interpret this or whether this is correct. I am also fairly new to statistics.
I would like some help understanding if this shape is expected for binary data or not, and generally what such a plot means.
spatial_model_gamm <- gamm4(
  Species1 ~ s(X, Y) + Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4,
  random = ~(1 | Dist_ID), 
  data = Data,
  family = binomial
)




It makes no sense to try to interpret the default residuals from a GAMM this way. What you see is exactly what you should expect to see if you plot the fitted values against the residuals. A better option is to get DHARMa residuals instead. The vignette here is especially helpful.

Hi Shawn, I see that you are quite knowledgeable on regression models and post great answers. I am stuck on these two problems and have a class assignment deadline soon approaching. Do you have any thoughts on these 2 questions?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658704/using-a-mixed-effects-model-to-understand-the-population

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658594/is-there-a-standard-way-to-calculate-marginal-effects

Looks like the other two posters have you covered in their answers in the links you sent.
