Using a mixed effects model to understand the population?
I have this repeated measures data in R (simulated) that represents multiple regions in the same country (i.e. multiple measurements over time for each region - assume regions are measured at the same time):
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(mgcv)
library(marginaleffects)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2002-01-01"), by = "month")
regions <- paste0("Region", 1:5)

simulated_data <- expand.grid(date = dates, region = regions) %>%
    mutate(
        time = as.numeric(date - as.Date("2000-01-01")),
        x1 = 100 + 0.1 * time + 2 * sin(2 * pi * time/365) + rnorm(n(), sd = 0.5),
        x2 = pmax(0, 5 + 10 * sin(2 * pi * time/180) + rnorm(n(), sd = 2)),
        y = pmin(100, pmax(0, 50 + 2 * (x1 - 100) + 3 * x2 + 
                               as.numeric(factor(region)) * 5 + rnorm(n(), sd = 5))),
        y_scaled = y/100
    )

The data looks like this:
        date  region time        x1        x2         y  y_scaled
1 2000-01-01 Region1    0  99.37333  5.974658  68.27660 0.6827660
2 2000-02-01 Region1   31 104.06168 15.506948 100.00000 1.0000000
3 2000-03-01 Region1   60 107.01112 17.803737 100.00000 1.0000000
4 2000-04-01 Region1   91 110.10850  6.202243  91.15382 0.9115382
5 2000-05-01 Region1  121 114.23521  0.000000  87.34234 0.8734234
6 2000-06-01 Region1  152 116.65292  0.000000  85.92773 0.8592773

I fit a mixed effects GAM regression to this data:
gam_model <- gam(
    y_scaled ~ te(time, x1) + te(time, x2) + 
        s(time, by = region) + s(region, bs = "re"),
    data = simulated_data,
    method = "REML",
    family = betar(link = "logit")
)

I then used this R code to get the marginal effects of x1 and x2 on time for each region:
effects_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(regions, function(current_region) {
    region_data <- simulated_data[simulated_data$region == current_region,]
    x1_effects <- slopes(gam_model, variables = "x1", newdata = region_data)
    x2_effects <- slopes(gam_model, variables = "x2", newdata = region_data)
    
    rbind(
        data.frame(
            time = region_data$time,
            fit = x1_effects$estimate * 100,
            ci_lower = x1_effects$conf.low * 100,
            ci_upper = x1_effects$conf.high * 100,
            effect_type = "X1",
            region = current_region
        ),
        data.frame(
            time = region_data$time,
            fit = x2_effects$estimate * 100,
            ci_lower = x2_effects$conf.low * 100,
            ci_upper = x2_effects$conf.high * 100,
            effect_type = "X2",
            region = current_region
        )
    )
}))

ggplot(effects_data, aes(x = time, color = effect_type, fill = effect_type)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.2, color = NA) +
    geom_line(aes(y = fit)) +
    facet_wrap(~region) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray50") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 730, 180),
                       labels = function(x) format(as.Date("2000-01-01") + x, "%Y-%m")) +
    labs(title = "Marginal Effects of X1 and X2 Over Time",
         x = "Time", 
         y = "Effect Size") +
    theme_minimal()


Based on this, I want to now calculate marginal effects for x1,x2 vs time at the population level.
I thought of a naive way to do this - simply average and aggregate across regions, and then continue with the marginal effects at the population level:
grid_data <- expand.grid(
    time = unique(simulated_data$time),
    x1 = mean(simulated_data$x1),
    x2 = mean(simulated_data$x2),
    region = regions
)

x1_effects <- slopes(
    gam_model,
    variables = "x1",
    newdata = grid_data,
    by = "time"
) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(
        fit = mean(estimate) * 100,
        ci_lower = mean(conf.low) * 100,
        ci_upper = mean(conf.high) * 100,
        .groups = "drop"
    ) %>%
    mutate(effect_type = "X1")

x2_effects <- slopes(
    gam_model,
    variables = "x2",
    newdata = grid_data,
    by = "time"
) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(
        fit = mean(estimate) * 100,
        ci_lower = mean(conf.low) * 100,
        ci_upper = mean(conf.high) * 100,
        .groups = "drop"
    ) %>%
    mutate(effect_type = "X2")

population_effects <- bind_rows(x1_effects, x2_effects)

ggplot(population_effects, aes(x = time, color = effect_type, fill = effect_type)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.2, color = NA) +
    geom_line(aes(y = fit)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray50") +
    scale_x_continuous(
        breaks = seq(0, 730, 180),
        labels = function(x) format(as.Date("2000-01-01") + x, "%Y-%m")
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "Population-Level Marginal Effects of X1 and X2 Over Time",
        subtitle = "Averaged across all regions",
        x = "Time",
        y = "Effect Size (%)"
    ) +
    theme_minimal()


While this seems to have worked, I am having doubts as I am not sure if this confidence intervals are correct. It seems like there is a proper method for calculating confidence intervals of marginal effects (e.g. How to calculate the standard error of the marginal effects in interactions (robust regression)?), and I am not sure if the approach I am using is an oversimplification or if it is correct.

An alternate marginal effects approach that uses observed information at each time point instead of averaged information throughout:
effects_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(regions, function(current_region) {
    region_data <- simulated_data[simulated_data$region == current_region,]
    x1_effects <- slopes(gam_model, variables = "x1", newdata = region_data)
    x2_effects <- slopes(gam_model, variables = "x2", newdata = region_data)
    
    rbind(
        data.frame(
            time = region_data$time,
            fit = x1_effects$estimate * 100,
            ci_lower = x1_effects$conf.low * 100,
            ci_upper = x1_effects$conf.high * 100,
            effect_type = "X1",
            region = current_region
        ),
        data.frame(
            time = region_data$time,
            fit = x2_effects$estimate * 100,
            ci_lower = x2_effects$conf.low * 100,
            ci_upper = x2_effects$conf.high * 100,
            effect_type = "X2",
            region = current_region
        )
    )
}))

time_specific_means <- simulated_data %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(
        x1_mean = mean(x1),
        x2_mean = mean(x2),
        .groups = "drop"
    )

grid_data <- time_specific_means %>%
    crossing(region = regions) %>%
    rename(x1 = x1_mean, x2 = x2_mean)

x1_effects <- slopes(
    gam_model,
    variables = "x1",
    newdata = grid_data,
    by = "time"
) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(
        fit = mean(estimate) * 100,
        ci_lower = mean(conf.low) * 100,
        ci_upper = mean(conf.high) * 100,
        .groups = "drop"
    ) %>%
    mutate(effect_type = "X1")

x2_effects <- slopes(
    gam_model,
    variables = "x2",
    newdata = grid_data,
    by = "time"
) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(
        fit = mean(estimate) * 100,
        ci_lower = mean(conf.low) * 100,
        ci_upper = mean(conf.high) * 100,
        .groups = "drop"
    ) %>%
    mutate(effect_type = "X2")

population_effects <- bind_rows(x1_effects, x2_effects)

ggplot(population_effects, aes(x = time, color = effect_type, fill = effect_type)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.2, color = NA) +
    geom_line(aes(y = fit)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray50") +
    scale_x_continuous(
        breaks = seq(0, 730, 180),
        labels = function(x) format(as.Date("2000-01-01") + x, "%Y-%m")
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "Population-Level Marginal Effects of X1 and X2 Over Time",
        subtitle = "Using time-specific means across regions",
        x = "Time",
        y = "Effect Size (%)"
    ) +
    theme_minimal()



If I understand your question correctly, you want to compute and plot:

Average slopes with respect to x1 and x2 for each combination of region and time.
Average slopes with respect to x1 and x2 for each time.

For this, you don’t need to go through all these complications. marginaleffects can do it all for you.
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)

s <- avg_slopes(gam_model, variables = c("x1", "x2"), by = c("region", "time")) |>
    transform(
        estimate = estimate * 100,
        conf.low = conf.low * 100,
        conf.high = conf.high * 100)

ggplot(s, aes(x = time, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = term)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(fill = term), alpha = 0.2) +
    facet_wrap(~ region)



s <- avg_slopes(gam_model, variables = c("x1", "x2"), by = "time") |>
    transform(
        estimate = estimate * 100,
        conf.low = conf.low * 100,
        conf.high = conf.high * 100)

ggplot(s, aes(x = time, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = term)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(fill = term), alpha = 0.2)



Thank you so much Vincent! Some questions I had:


In the second plot that you made, when you wrote "Average slopes with respect to x1 and x2 for each time" ... this is can be thought of as the country level plot? My understanding is the following: at each observed time point, we take the average value of x1 and x2 (from all regions). E.g. (time=1, x1-bar = a1, x2-bar = b1), (time=2, x1-bar = a2, x2-bar=b2) etc .....then: at each time point, we use these tuples to evaluate the marginal effect of these variables on the response. Thus, we have a country level marginal effects. correct?



In the first plot (i.e. the panel of 5 plots) that you made, you are using the avg_slopes() function whereas I used the slopes() function.  Our plots look identical. Take the plot for Region 1: are you holding x1 and x2 at their average values observed in Region 1 ? i.e. if  (time=1,x1-bar=a,x2-bar=b), (time=2, x1-bar=a, x2-bar=b) .... or are you changing the values of x1 and x2 to reflect their observed values? e.g. (time=1, x1-bar = a1, x2-bar = b1), (time=2, x1-bar = a2, x2-bar=b2) ?


A lot of my confusion comes from this post here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658594/is-there-a-standard-way-to-calculate-marginal-effects

Not quite. First, we compute dy/dx1 and dy/dx2 for each row of the original data. Then, we take the average of these unit-level estimates for each time point. I strongly recommend you read chapters 3 and 7 from this free online book: https://marginaleffects.com
